# PyQt signal and sqlalchemy: how to properly handle object expiration

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyqt

We're developing python an application that uses Qt and sqlalchemy with a single long lived session. Some of the objects we load from the db are long lived too and fire Qt signals to signal changes. For this to work, we use double inheritance with a custom meta-class and init the QObject base class from the `@orm.reconstructor`:

```
class LongLived(QObject, Base):
    __metaclass__ = DeclarativeQObjectMeta
    # ... column declarations ...

    something_changed = pyqtSignal(object)

    @orm.reconstructor
    def init_on_load(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
```

The problem with this approach is that `init_on_load` is called whenever someone accesses the object after it has expired (i.e. after every commit). This then re-initializes QObject which seems to kill all signal connections in the process.

What's the proper way to keep PyQt signals/slots connected to an object that may expire (other than setting `expire_on_commit=False`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since sqlalchemy and Qt/PyQt are very special in their handling of object lifecycle it's probably not a good idea to mix those two.

Maybe you can think about maintaining one, long-lived QObject and use SQLAlchemy event listeners to signal attribute changes (using [SQLAlchemy example](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#attribute-events)):

```
_qobject = None
def validate_phone(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    "Notify about phone number change"
    if _qobject is None:
        _qobject = YourQObjectImplementation()

    _qobject.something_changed.emit(target, value, oldvalue)
    return value

# setup listener on UserContact.phone attribute, instructing
# it to use the return value
listen(UserContact.phone, 'set', validate_phone)
```

You could obviously make the creation and storage of the `_qobject` much more sophisticated (per session, per application, thread-local, etc.) and you'd have to create listeners to all interesting attributes (you can use other SQLAlchemy events for that in turn).
I'm aware that's not a ready-made solution, but might be a helpful, different approach.